# Convert binary file to text and back

Tags: java, kotlin

I need to convert a binary file to the text file in Java/Kotlin. Something like 50 4b 03 04 14 00... that can be stored as ASCII text. Then revert it back to binary. The main goal is reverted file should work as expected. If it is a zip-archive it should be able to unpack, if it is executable, it should be able to execute, etc.

Comment: Is it a goal for the text version to be human-readable (and maybe human-editable)?  Or can it be opaque, as long as it can be safely stored as plain ASCII and converted back to binary without loss?

Comment: Nope. The goal is store and transfer binary as a text. The Base64 solution is appropriate for me. I mostly used the Base64 for text encoding only and looked out of sight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All roads for converting from binary to text and back will lead you to [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), which is the most common standard for encoding binary to ascii text and back again.

There's plenty of Base64 libraries for Java and Kotlin.

Start here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-base64-encode-and-decode

Looks like Java 8 has a native Base64 class built in: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html

Kotlin example: https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/strings-base64-encode-decode-guide